# Directional Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question I have requires me to find all of the directions for which the directional derivative at the point $(0,0)$ exists, and the corresponding directional derivatives. This is an assignment question so please don't give me the explicit answer!

Firstly I let $f(x,y)=|x-y|= \sqrt{(x-y)^2}$ to get $f_x = \frac{x-y}{|x-y|}$ and similarly, $f_y = \frac{y-x}{|x-y|}$ (if that helps me)

Now let **u** be the unit vector $(x_0,y_0)$

From here I am stuck:

The following is an attempt:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(0,0)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{ f(0+tx_0,0+ty_0) - f(0,0)}{t} =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{ (tx_0-ty_0)^2}}{t}=\pm|x_0-y_0|=0$$

From here I would conclude that the directional derivative exists in all such directions, and is equal to $0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you don't want the explicit answer I'll just talk you through it.

When $ u=(x_0,y_0)$ is a vector in which's direction you plan to differentiate, you only know that $ ||u|| = 1 $.

So in your example $ \nabla_{u} f(x)  = \displaystyle \lim_{t\to0} \frac{f(x+tu)-f(x)}{t} = \lim_{t\to0} \frac{|t||x_0-y_0|}{t} = |x_0-y_0|\lim_{t\to0} \frac{|t|}{t} $

So note that we were able to get $ |x_0-y_0| $ out of the limit because when you have already factored it out it doesn't depend on $t$. Look at the limit on the right, use different approaches to $0$. You already know that $ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{|x|}{x} $ does not exist, but you also know that
$ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{|x|}{x} = 1, \lim_{x\to0^-} \frac{|x|}{x} = -1 $

So you should ask yourself: What conditions must $ u = (x_0,y_0) $ satisfy in order to get the same limit ?.

I think this answers your question, you only have to do one little step.

Comment: So would $x_0$ have to be equal to $y_0$ ? So the directional vector $u=(x_0,y_0)$ has to be the vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$. Please confirm!

Comment: Correct. That's what you can conclude.

Comment: Apologies -  I have done so now! :)